# .vimrc being overwritten. Not all settings working

Tags: vim

My ~/.vim/.vimrc seems to be overwritten as some custom settings seem to work whilst others don't. For example `set number` does not work. 
If i type `:set number` in vim it does work. If i do vim 'filename' -u 'path/to/.vimrc' it does work

I have looked into this and one post suggested updating from the mac vim 7.3 to 7.4 but that didn't seem to do the trick.

:version

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Dec 15 2015 16:09:04)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-963
Compiled by Homebrew

system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
```

Comment: It's `~/.vim/vimrc` or `~/.vimrc`; not `~/.vim/.vimrc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vimrc config files  are searched in the order the first that exists
    is used, the others are ignored.  The $MYVIMRC environment variable is
    set to the file that was first found, unless $MYVIMRC was already set
    and when using VIMINIT.

From your `:version` output, vim looks for user vimrc files in order:

```
...
user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
...
```

If you have `$HOME/.vimrc` file, it will be read and used for vim configuration.

If you don't have that file, your `~/.vim/.vimrc` will not be read any way, because  vim looks for `"~/.vim/vimrc"` without the `dot`.

Answer (score 0):

A similar thing happened to me once. Try putting the lines which you think are getting overridden, at the end of the file. 
So, in this case try with `set nu`

If this does, then you can be sure that some other command in the middle is messing it up. 
So, try it and see if it that resolves it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried starting with a blank vimrc file with just `set nu` in and it still does not work